# New to remote database connection in C#

Tags: database

Is there any book or tutorial for connecting to a database running on a remote server? I have experience only with local databases in C# .NET 2.0 (SQLite, Firebird), but now I need to place the database on a remote server. Are there any differences when compared to local databases? Any books you could recommend? To be honest I don't know what to look for.

EDIT: thanks for the replies, I know there will be very few changes in the connection strings etc. What I wanted to know was things like the data transfer is much slower, i.e. I cannot make huge selects and transfer all rows as I do it now, I should make separate thread for data connections etc. I am just guessing here, since all is new to me. Just some "best practices" or so.

Thanks,
Petr

Comment: There is very little difference between local and remote. Programmatically-speaking the code doesn't look any different. Just your connection string will change and perhaps the configuration of the server. (You might have to explicitly configure it to allow network connections.) There is no other change... unless you put the db behind a web service. Then you'd need a book recommendation. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The only relevant difference is the name of the server inside the connection string :)

Answer (score 2):

Which SQL Server you want to use.

You could look for ADO.NET. I accept to Lorenzo, nothing will be changed in the Source Code, only your Connection String need to be edited.

**Very cool ConnectionString Info and Generator Page:**

http://www.connectionstrings.com/